# Preparando servidor Linux de desenvolvimento

Tags: php, linux

Estou utilizando a distro Debian 9 em meu servidor, ao vasculhar os pacotes do PHP observei que php-fpm parece ser um alias para php7.0-fpm.

Caso eu esteja correto, posso instalar meus pacotes assim:

```
apt-get install php-fpm php-mysql php-curl php-json php-mcrypt php-imagick php-mbstring php-xml -y
```

ou assim:

```
apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-imagick php7.0-mbstring php7.0-xml -y
```

E o resultado final será exatamente o mesmo, ou seja, em ambos os casos a versão final instalada será 7.0. Estou correto?

Comment: Se você executar as duas formas, vai obter o mesmo resultado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso **os dois comandos vão instalar o PHP 7.0**

O que define qual será instalada por padrão ao executar o comando sem especificar a versão é o repositório da distribuição.

Até o Debian 8 (Jessie) o PHP padrão era o 5.6, mas a partir do Debian 9 (Stretch) a versão padrão do PHP se tornou o 7.0.

Você pode esta e outras novidades do Debian 9 aqui: [What's new in Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação.